# How merge a couple of SQLite3 Databases with each other

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Hi iam trying t merge a couple of databases with each other.
I have the following code to search for the databases, and then combine them.

```
import os
import glob
import sqlite3


con3 = sqlite3.connect("./combine.SQL")  #Empty DB


directory_with_databases = "./unpacked/" #folder with "full" *.sql dbs


databases = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_with_databases, "*.SQL"))


for filename in databases:
    con3.execute("ATTACH ? as dba", (filename,))

    for row in con3.execute ("SELECT * FROM dba.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'") :
        combine = "INSERT INTO " + row[1] + " SELECT * FROM dba." + row[1]
        print (combine)
        con3.execute (combine)

    con3.commit ()

    con3.execute("detach database dba")
```

When executing the code i get the follwing error:

```
con3.execute (combine)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: PLschemaVersions.ID
```

Can somebody help me to complete the code

Comment: What do you want to have happen when you insert a row that has a conflict?

Comment: Start with https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html for some options for automatically handling such cases.

Comment: @Shawn the only thing i want to happen is that the databases which have the same layout are merged together.
So if you know a other way please tell me :-)

Comment: Please provide some details about the schemas of the tables you want to merge, e.g. using `.schema`.